# A Robot's Last Words

Tags: logical-deduction, computer-puzzle, circuitry

There, spread out all over the floor, were the mechanical pieces of a robot. Something had torn it apart, and the debris spanned a radius of a few meters. There was no sign of what might have caused this tragedy. What monster, what disaster, could cause this much damage to a mechanical creature?

However, a few steps away, there was a hastily constructed circuit:

[image: What happened here?]

And one question nags at you:

***What was the robot trying to tell us with his last words?***

Comment: Wow! Nice intuitive riddle... just one question - how the hell did you come up with the boolean formulas from the results/truth-table ?

Comment: @Falco: a naive approach would be to take all rows where a certain bit evaluates to 1 and `OR` them. But a better way is to build a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) for each bit, which gives you the simplest boolean expression equivalent to the naive one.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Answer:

> KEEPAWAY

Explanation:

Here are the functions for the output (in Java).

```
Output 1 = !((!C)|C)
Output 2 = (!C)|C
Output 3 = !((!C)|C)
Output 4 = (A|B)&C
Output 5 = (!(A^B))&(!(B^C))
Output 6 = ((!A)&(B^C))|((A&C)&(!B))
Output 7 = ((A&C)&(!B))|(!((B|C)|A))
Output 8 = (!(B&C))|A
```

Using these functions

> you can create a Truth table:
>
> `|A|B|C|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|Hex|Char|
> --------------------------------
> |0|0|0|0|1|0|0|1|0|1|1|4b |K   |
> |0|0|1|0|1|0|0|0|1|0|1|45 |E   |
> |0|1|0|0|1|0|0|0|1|0|1|45 |E   |
> |0|1|1|0|1|0|1|0|0|0|0|50 |P   |
> |1|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|1|41 |A   |
> |1|0|1|0|1|0|1|0|1|1|1|57 |W   |
> |1|1|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|1|41 |A   |
> |1|1|1|0|1|0|1|1|0|0|1|59 |Y   |`
>
> From this truth table it is obvious what the message is.

Comment: Completely correct!

Comment: This is clever, @Tryth, and I enjoyed solving it. I'm curious how the message ties in with the story, however.

Comment: @JoshCaswell My idea was that whatever destroyed the robot was so dangerous that with his last seconds he created a warning for others. Not sure how well it was conveyed though.

Comment: Sounds like you set yourself up for a sequel, @Tryth!

Comment: @Tryth I don't think the answer is completely correct. I think there is a mistake in upper cases vs. lower case.

Comment: @Tryth No, I did not work backwards. I used [UTF-16](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.htm) to translate the code points.

Comment: Outputs 1 and 3 appear wired identically, and in your Java definition, they are defined the same. So why is 1 always 0 and 3 always 1?

Comment: @AFischBein Fixed, strangely the fix makes all the letters upper case as kasperd suggested.

Comment: @TheBestOne - lowercase letters are 32 more than uppercase counterparts in ASCII (e.g. 'A'=65, 'a'=97). Output 3 is in the 6th position, starting from the right, corresponding to  value 2^5. Switching output 3 from 1 to 0 subtracts 2^5, or 32 from the value, converting lowercase to uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the bottom output as bit 0 up to the top output as bit 7.  You can easily see that bits 5, 6, and 7 are always 010. Given that I wrote the following Python code (without looking at any answers to make it more fun!):

```
def bit0(a, b, c):
    return a or not (b and c)
def bit1(a, b, c):
    return bit1_5(a, b, c) or not (a or b or c)
def bit1_5(a, b, c):
    return (a and c) and not b
def bit2(a, b, c):
    return (not a and (b != c)) or bit1_5(a, b, c)
def bit3(a, b, c):
    return a == b == c
def bit4(a, b, c):
    return (a or b) and c

def compose(i):
    a = bool(i & 0x04)
    b = bool(i & 0x02)
    c = bool(i & 0x01)
    bits = 0b01000000
    if bit0(a, b, c):
        bits |= 0b00000001
    if bit1(a, b, c):
        bits |= 0b00000010
    if bit2(a, b, c):
        bits |= 0b00000100
    if bit3(a, b, c):
        bits |= 0b00001000
    if bit4(a, b, c):
        bits |= 0b00010000
    return bits

if __name__ == '__main__':
    message = ''
    for i in range(8):
        message += chr(compose(i))
    print (message)
```

Which outputs:

> KEEPAWAY